# Prove that $\{x \in [a,b] \cap \mathbb Q : d(x) \le r \}$ is a finite set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

For each rational number like $x$, it can be written in the form $\frac{p}{q}$ such that $(p,q)=1$ and $q \ge 1$.

Assume that for each $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb Q$ holding the conditions of the above sentence, $d(\frac{p}{q})=q$.  So, If $z$ is an integer, For example, $d(z)=1$.

Assume that $r\in \mathbb R^+$ is given.  Prove that $\{x \in [a,b] \cap \mathbb Q : d(x) \le r \}$ is a finite set.

Note : I know how to show that a set is countable ( by finding a bijective function from the set to $\mathbb N$). I know there are two kinds of countable sets, finite and infinite. But i don't know how to show that this set is not just countable, but also finite.  In this case, i think i don't really know what are the members of this set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even describe this set (let's call it $X$) precisely:
$$
X = \bigcup_{i=1}^r\{x\in [a,b]:d(x) = i \} = \bigcup_{i=1}^r X_i.
$$
Now, $X_i$ spans from $\lfloor ia\rfloor/i$ to $\lceil ib\rceil/i$ including them, with a step of $1/i$. Obviously it is finite, and a union we take is finite as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the set would be infinite, there would need to be infinitely many $x \in [a,b]$ with $d(x) = q$ for some $q$. This leads to a contradiction since for sufficiently small $p$, holds $\frac{p}{q} < a$ and for sufficiently large $p$, holds $\frac{p}{q} > b$.